# if $f: X \to X$ is continuous where $X$ is a topological space with a cofinite topology, then:

Tags: general-topology

if $f: X \to X$ is continuous where $X$ is a topological space with a cofinite topology, then:

$$(i)  \ f^{-1}(x) \text{ is finite for all $x$} \\ \text{or} \\ (ii) \ f \text{ is constant}$$

My approach:

I couldn't build up a proper approach here to be honest. I believe we need to use the fact that inverse functions preserve differences of sets. But couldn't go on.

Any hints?

Comment: (ii) is certainly false as $X$ might have more than one point and $f$ be the identity

Comment: It would help if you stated the problem correctly. What you must prove is that EITHER $f^{-1}(x)$ is finite FOR EVERY $x$ **or else** $f$ is constant.

Comment: There are many properties that are equivalent to continuity. For example $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}B$ is closed in $X$ whenever $B$ is closed in $Y.$ This one should be applied to the Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pre-image of every point is finite, you are done.

Otherwise there is a point with infinite pre-image. But single points are closed, so the pre-image must be closed. The only closed set that is NOT finite is all of $X$. So now you have a point whose pre-image is all of $X$, which means $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

First, every point set $\{x\}$ is a closed set, the continuity of $f$ implies that $f^{-1}(x)$ is a closed set in $X$. Hence, $(f^{-1}(x))^c$ is an open set in $X$. So it has to be a finite set.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f^{-1}(X\setminus \{ x\}) = X\setminus f^{-1}(\{x\})$ must be open.

Comment: why are we sure that $x$ is in the topology on $X$?

Comment: I only used $X\setminus \{ x\}$ is in the topology.

Answer (score 0):

In a cofinite space $X$ the only closed sets are the finite subsets and $X$. A function is continuous iff the inverse image of a closed set is closed.

So either all sets $f^{-1}[\{x\}]$ are finite, or one of them (there can only be at most one, of course )
has $f^{-1}[\{x\}] = X$ in which case $f$ is constant.

So the named options are exactly the mutually exclusive options for $f$: constant or finite fibres.

Comment: Would you care to explain the difference between your answer and mine? What, the fact that you included the definition of the cofinite topology? Is that a sufficient difference to justify posting exactly the same answer again?